# A regex expression that can remove data from a json object

Tags: json, regex

I'd like to be able to selectively remove elements from a json schema.  Imagine a json object that contains a larger but similar array of users like this

```
[{
    "users": [{
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "socialSecurityNumber": "123-45-6789",
        "sex": "Female",
        "id": "1234",
        "race": "Smith",
        "lastName": "Logan"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Charles",
        "socialSecurityNumber": "321-54-9876",
        "sex": "Male",
        "id": "3456",
        "race": "White",
        "lastName": "Clifford"
    }],
```

I'd like to strip the socialSecurityNumber element from the json schema using a regex expression. What would a regex expression to remove

```
"socialSecurityNumber": "whatever value",
```

look like where the value of the data pair could be any string?

I cannot be certain of the position of the data pair and whether it would have a trailing comma.

Comment: You should not be using regular expressions for this, but rather a JSON parser.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I deserialize the json object and then run through the structure to remove the unwanted data?

Comment: Absolutely.  Anything else will have weird failure conditions.

Comment: Yes, I sugest a JSON parser too, UNLESS you can guarantee that the parts you want to remove are ALWAYS in the same line. Where did this JSON come from?

Comment: It's coming from a Coldfusion/Hibernate ORM entity.  I can't guarantee that the parts will always be in the same line.  I'm not familiar with JSON parsers.  Can you name some common parsers? The JSON will be returned as a RESTful service response and so the processing needs to be done in Coldfusion before it leaves the server.

Comment: [python has one built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: I ended up removing selected elements iterating through the results structure to remove the ones I didn't want. Some elements are a couple of levels deep from the root context and the nested iteration gets expensive with several hundred records. It would sure be nice to do some direct text transformation on a flat JSON file. I thought regex would be a nice fit but the contributors here reasonably commented that it's a bad idea, given the potential to corrupt the json file. A quick glance at examples of JSON parsers look like iterators to me. Any other solutions that are less iterative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the following regular expression with empty:

```
"socialSecurityNumber": "(\d|\-)",
```

It can go wrong if this info is split in 2 lines, or if the SSN is the last user field, because there will be no comma after it.

Anyway, after the replacing operation, check if there are any string

```
"socialSecurityNumber"
```

to confirm this can be used. If there are still strings that weren't replaced, then you will need a JSON parser to correctly eliminate this information.